# fork() and "\n"

Tags: c, fork

I just made a simple demo program in `C` to see how `fork()` works and came across something that I don't understand. In this example:

```
void fork2()
{
    printf("A");
    fork();
    printf("B");
}
```

The output is `ABAB`, but in this example:

```
void fork2()
{
    printf("A\n");
    fork();
    printf("B\n");
}
```

The output is `ABB` (separate lines of course). The second one makes sense, because if I understand `fork()` correctly it spawns a new child that starts right after where the `fork()` took place (so `printf("B\n");` in this case). What I don't understand, is why the output is different when I include the new line character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`printf()` buffers output until a newline is encountered. So your `\n`-less version stuffs `A` into the output buffer, forks.

Since both processes are identical (minus PIDs and whatnot), they now both have an output buffer that contains `A`.

The execution continues and prints `B` into the buffers in each process. Both processes then exit, causing a flush of the output buffer, which prints `AB` twice, once for each process.

You other version, having `\n`, causes that output buffer to flush after the first printf() call, and when the fork hits, both processes have an empty buffer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *do not* define a `fork()` function in your code. `fork()` is a *system call* already defined for you.

You call `fork()` and once it (successfully) returns, you have two identical processes executing the next line of the code past the `fork()` invocation. In the parent process `fork()` will return the PID of the child; in the child process the return code is 0. based on this return code, your two processes can do whatever they intended to based on their roles.

Now, there is *no guarantee* on relative order of execution of these two processes. For all you know, child might not execute for the next 2 minutes and it would still be the correct behavior. So, this means you cannot expect the order of the output from *both* of those processes to be predictable.

Finally, change `printf()` to `fprintf()` to avoid buffering (which confuses things further in this case).

Comment: I actually called it fork2() but removed the 2 here because I thought it would read easier. makes sense though what you said, so i'll change it back now.

Comment: This “answer” does not answer the question. The question is primarily about why “A” is printed twice in the first case (and once in the second), not about the order of printing.