# printf newline has line buffer?

Tags: c, linux, fork

Language: C, OS: Linux

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
    fork();
    printf("hello world\n");
    fork();
    printf("bye\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello world
bye
hello world
bye
hello world
bye
hello world
bye
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20252964/5946290) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork), `printf() buffers output until a newline is encountered`.

So why does we have 4 "hello world" in this case? (instead of 2 "hello world")

**Edit**: Sorry all, but like @GregHewgill said, I running this program from an environment where the output cannot be directly to the terminal, when I check it again on my computer, it just run as expected.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your output (gcc 4.8.1).

Comment: Line buffering is only one *possible* strategy `printf` can implement. The only sure way to flush an output stream is `fflush`.

Comment: I get different output with  i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4 in cygwin

Comment: "So why does we have 4 "hello world" in this case?" --> What output were you expecting?

Comment: @chux 2 hello world and 4 bye

Comment: @chux, They are expecting the output to have been sent to disk before the second fork, and thus only get two instances of the message

Comment: Is it C or the OS doing the buffering here...?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ubuntu 12 (gcc 4.6.3) unless I redirect the output (e.g. `a | cat`). This switches from line buffering to block buffering.

Comment: Are you running this from a shell command line, or are you running it in some environment where the output may not be *directly* to a terminal device?

Comment: Sorry all, but like @GregHewgill said, I running this program from an environment where the output cannot be directly to the terminal, when I check it again on my computer, it just run as expected.

Answer (score 2):

> According to this and this, printf() buffers output until a newline is encountered.

Printing a newline usually flushes only if the output goes to a terminal device.
For example:

```
$ ./a.out >out_file
```

will not flush the buffer even with the newline character. So, your expectation is flawed.

The only right way to get "desired" output (2 `hello world` and 4 `bye`) is to either disable buffering totally using [`setbuf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html):

```
setbuf(stdout, 0);
```

or use [`fflush`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html):

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after each `printf` call to flush explicitly.

Comment: It should be sufficient to ensure that the stream is line-buffered, which can be done via `setvbuf()`.  It should not be necessary to disable buffering altogether, though perhaps that would be safer.